# xml parsing error

Tags: xml, ocs

I am writing a ocs IM client for android and now I am trying to delete a contact from contact list with the

```
<deleteContact rid="100"></deleteContact>
 <uri>sip:alice@contoso.com</uri>
</deleteContact>
```

command request to the cwa server... the command is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb969527%28v=office.12%29.aspx.

When I send the request to the ocs server I get the following error:

```
Error in XML document (5, 3): deleteContact was not expected
```

Does somebody know what could be the problem? Or at least tell me please how can I read that error: document (5, 3) ...

My original code:

```
<cwaRequests sid="5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/rtc/cwa">
  <deleteContact rid="2">
   <uri>
    sip:emil@domain.org
   </uri>
 </deleteContact>
</cwaRequests>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the closing deleteContact tag in the first line:

```
<deleteContact rid="100"></deleteContact>
 <uri>sip:alice@contoso.com</uri>
</deleteContact>
```

should be

```
<deleteContact rid="100">
 <uri>sip:alice@contoso.com</uri>
</deleteContact>
```

Comment: sorry, that code is copy -> paste from the url above... I send the request without that closing tag...

Comment: my request is this:  <cwaRequests sid="5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/rtc/cwa"> <deleteContact rid="2">
 <uri>
 sip:emil@domain.org
 </uri>
 </deleteContact>
 </cwaRequests>

Comment: there is a semi-colon (";") at the end of the <cwaRequests> opening tag - you'll need to get rid of that

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include your message xml _exactly_ as you are sending it?

Comment: Where did mcxRequests come from? CWA needs the root tags to be cwaRequests, and the schema to be http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/rtc/cwa

Comment: sorry, I have posted a wrong request for the first time.. I have the cwaRequests

Comment: It all looks fine to me - it seems that your CWA server is rejecting it because it fails validation against a schema. I would have a look on the CWA server and see if you can find the XSD that it is using to validate, and see if that sheds any light